# How to combine AND and OR operators using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to make SQL requests that would implement this behavior:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (created_at > '2010/01/01' AND created_at < '2010/12/01') OR (created_at > '2012/01/01' AND created_at < '2012/12/31')
```

The goal is to have a request that returns results from a list of selected years (that might not be consecutive, we might have 2010 and 2012 without 2011).

Any clue how I would achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try some SQL in the where method

```
Table.where(
  'created_at between ? and ? or created_at between ? and ?', 
  date1,
  date2,
  date3,
  date4
)
```

Also, as a useful hint for debugging these queries. Once you've got your query, you can call to_sql to see the literal SQL result.

```
User.where(admin: true).to_sql
```

Comment: P.S. I'm not entirely sure if you can use the between keyword in postresql, but you should be able to inject appropriate SQL in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel)

```
t = User.arel_table

results = User.where(t[:created_at].gt( '2010-01-01').and(t[:created_at].lt('2010-12-01')).
or(t[:created_at].gt('2012-01-01').and(t[:created_at].lt('2012-12-31'))))
```

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid this approach unlesss you want to spend a long time reading and understanding the Arel API. It's valid, but it is a heavy-weight learning process.

Comment: True, but ActiveRecord uses Arel to build the queries and ultimately calls out to it to get the final SQL before shipping it to the database of your choice.

Comment: True, it does go via Arel, and there is at least two ways to access it. I quite like the usability layer in the ActiveRecord adapter for Arel, tho. :)

Comment: That would be the optimum solution, since I'm using Ransack. But there's no combinations of AND and OR operators in this query, only a OR. I haven't found how to generate the query from my original post using Arel.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [any_of](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of) gem:

```
Table.where.any_of(Table.where(created_at: t1..t2), Table.where(created_at: t3..t4))
```

t1, t2, t3 and t4, being the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using:

```
where('created_at > ? AND created_at < ? OR created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', Time.new(2010,1,1), Time.new(2010,12,1), Time.new(2010,1,1), Time.new(2012,1,1), Time.new(2012,12,31))
```